# How to get auto-generated headers with pm.request.headers in Postman?

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have a Postman pre-request script which uses `pm.sendRequest` to call an endpoint that uses the same authorisation as the current request. I tried to use `pm.request.headers` in the script to get the Authorization header so I could add the same header in the `pm.sendRequest` call, but it doesn’t return the auto-generated headers, only the headers I’ve set manually. Is there any way to access the auto-generated headers in a pre-request script?

I tried

```
header: {
    "Authorization": pm.request.headers.get("Authorization"),
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to access the auto-generated headers, but you can actually access the data from the `Authorization` tab of Postman and thus also the access token:

```
pm.request.auth.parameters().get("accessToken")
```

I use this for setting the `token` parameter to a Postman variable named `token_param` when hitting the OIDC token introspection endpoint after having authenticated via OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow in a browser tab from Postman:

```
pm.variables.set('token_param', pm.request.auth.parameters().get("accessToken"))
```

You can also check what's inside the `auth` object by calling the `toJSON` method:

```
console.info(pm.request.auth.toJSON())
```

That way I found the `accessToken`:

[image: accessToken in auth object]

Comment: It's not working for me because my auth is inherited from the parent. 'pm.request.auth` is `undefined`.